# Shifting tables when filling a form created in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, forms

[image: Problem image]

I am creating a form with the developer's tool. I use the grey fields to add an area where people filling the forms can write in to answer the various questions. Some of those grey fields are in tables. I then protect the document so that only the grey fields can be modified/write-in.

The problem: There seems to be some kind of glitch where the tables and their backgrounds shift and become very messy when filling the form and writing in the grey-fields.

Anyone know how to correct this problem?

Comment: It sounds like maybe the table cells are not set to a fixed size, but instead allowed to adjust column width based on contents.

Comment: Indeed, the users filling the forms can add more text (no limits), and the table does extend well regarding this. It is just a kind of temporary glitch (but similar on different computer) where the background of the tables shift and the outlines disappear. But when clicking multiple times, and switching from page to page, the table readjust and reappear normal.

Comment: Please edit your question to include more details regarding how the fields shift around.

Comment: Are you doing this in Word? ("Office" is an entire suite of applications.) Please do not respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.